# Why do we say "so much more" rather than "so more "? Why do we have to put the much in?

Tags: adverbs, quantifiers

If the definition of the word *so* is an extent, then why do we have to put another word that describes a quantity after it, as "so much more" or "so much better"?

Why can't we just say, so more or so better ? Is there an explanation for this or is it just because it sounds right ?

Comment: Because *so* goes with *much* not *more*. It's either just *more* or it's "so much" more:  E.g., *This one is better.*  **or** *This one is* ***so much*** *better.*

Answer (score 3):

You need the *"much"* because *"more"* is a comparator. We don't say: *so stronger*, *so better*, *so worse*, *so more curious* but *so much stronger, so much better, so much worse, so much more curious.*

Why do we need *"much"* when you combine *"so"* with comparators? I think this is just the way English works. In French, you can just say *so better* (*tellement mieux*).

Answer (score 1):

What is being intensified in your example is not the comparative itself but the *degree of difference* warranting the comparative.

By the way, in formal register the use of “so” as intensifier creates the expectation of a result clause, which may or may not be introduced with “that”:

> Widget *A* is so much better than Widget *B* **that it fairly flies off the shelves at twice the price.**

This expectation is or can be **so** strong **that** a classic joke formula depends on it: “My home town was so small . . .” [Chorused audience response] “How small was it?” “. . . the general store only sold privates!” [rim shot].

Answer (score 1):

Rather than disecting the individual words of 'so much more', think of the cluster 'so much; so many' as an adjectival phrase modifying more and better. It's the 'so' that forces the 'much'. We could just as easily say : 'We have more time than we used to have', 'We did better than we thought.' For emphasis we throw in 'so much' to emphasize 'more' and 'better'. English is a language of timing and rhythm. Say 'so more' aloud. Then say 'so much more' and you'll see what I mean.