# What are the differences between "so" and "so much"?

Tags: determiners, adverb-position

When I received your email, I was so much glad.

Do you think that, in above sentence, the use of "so much" is correct? What should I use? If I use, "so" instead of "so much", does the meaning of sentence remain same? Please tell when "so" is used, and when "so much" is used.

Comment: Answered at [Why do we say “so much more” rather than “so more ”? Why do we have to put the much in?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177999/why-do-we-say-so-much-more-rather-than-so-more-why-do-we-have-to-put-the-m).

Comment: The correct syntax is: "Wow. So email.  Much receive.  Wow."

Comment: ... I was SO glad. Here, "so" is operating as an adverb and would receive the same punctuation rules of other adverbs. Review your sentence and determine whether SO is operating as a conjunction or an adverb. The rest will make sense with a little practice.

Comment: This is an English idiom. You can say "so very glad," but "so much glad" would identify you as a foreign learner.

Answer (score 2):

SO is a coordinating conjunction equivalent to "and," "but," and "or." It follows the same punctuation rules. Other forms of SO are different parts of speech. SO THAT specifically does not require a comma when used preceding the predicate part of a sentence. SO MUCH is an adverbial phrase (in every context I can think of) and would not require a comma on either side. You can usually avoid the word "that" following SO MUCH.
"I love you so much that I would die for you" verses "I love you so much I would die for you." SO MUCH modifies the verb "love."

Comment: Is this an archaic form, or do people use 'so' in this fashion? The kids enjoyed laughing so, at some of the funny faces I had made.